# Extract some JSON using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, open-uri

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.highcharts.com/demo/"))

puts doc
```

But I want to be able to extract the json from this webpage, using regular expressions doesn't seem to work, and how to do extract JSON through XPath?

Comment: The URL you have supplied does not *have* any JSON data in it. (There are some JavaScript object literals, e.g. the argument to `new Highcharts.Chart(...)`, but these are not actually JSON.) Is it the raw JavaScript data that you are trying to extract, or are you trying to get some other data from somewhere? **What are you really trying to accomplish?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you can access the script tags (that don't reference an external file) from a URL:

```ruby
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.HTML(open('http://www.highcharts.com/demo/'))
inline_script = doc.xpath('//script[not(@src)]')
inline_script.each do |script|
  puts "-"*50, script.text
end
```

Now you just need to find the script block you want and extract just the data you want (using regex). Without more details, it's hard to guess what you want and are relying upon.

Here's a fairly fragile regex that finds what I'm guessing you were looking for:

```ruby
inline = doc.xpath('//script[not(@src)]').map(&:text)
data   = inline.map{ |js| js[/new Highcharts\.Chart\((.+?\})\);/m,1] }.compact[0]
puts data
```

Here's what you get out:

```js
{
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    defaultSeriesType: 'line',
    marginRight: 130,
    marginBottom: 25
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
    x: -20 //center
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
    x: -20
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
      'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Temperature (°C)'
    },
    plotLines: [{
      value: 0,
      width: 1,
      color: '#808080'
    }]
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
        this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';
    }
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -10,
    y: 100,
    borderWidth: 0
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
  }, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
  }, {
    name: 'Berlin',
    data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
  }, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
  }]
}
```

Note that **this is not [JSON](http://json.org)**; this is a string representing JavaScript code with object, string, array, numeric, and function literals.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer, I was actually trying to extract the series part of the JavaScript code, Thanks for pointing out that its not json.

Answer (score 5):

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
doc = JSON.parse(open("http://www.highcharts.com/demo/"))
```

Comment: It will not work, because page has mixed content - HTML with javascript.

Comment: btw you need to require 'open-uri' and .read the open result cause it's a StringIO Object. doc = JSON.parse(open('xxxxx').read))

Comment: @pguardiario I'm sorry I can't help myself but how in the world a question be wrong? And if the question is "wrong" as you say it, then the answer is equally as useless?